# Cite software/libraries using bibtex

Tags: bibtex, citing

I would like to cite some sofware libraries I am using in a program using bibtex, but I can't quite figure out how to make that work properly. An entry might look like this:

```
@misc{CGAL,
  key   = "CGAL",
  title = "\textsc{Cgal}, {C}omputational {G}eometry {A}lgorithms {L}ibrary",
  note  = "http://www.cgal.org"
}
```

The problem is that `@misc` is not working optimally for me: Specifically the key (using `\bibliographystyle{alpha}`) is "CGA" instead of "CGAL", and I don't know how to fix that. Can I define my own style for citing software or can I at least change the key that is used for referencing?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; have you directly downloaded the `.bib` citation file somewhere? I believe you are free to define your own citekey as it will not appear in the final document. It is just an internal reference for BibTeX.

Comment: I mean the key that does appear in the document: If I put \cite{CGAL} in my tex file, then the result is [CGA] and not [CGAL], which I would prefer

Comment: Oh, I see, sorry for being so thick. I think the `key` that you enter in the `.bib` entry is not supposed to be the `citekey` which appears in the document, and which is generated by the BibTeX style that you choose: a number if you use `unsrt` for instance, or a combination of letters with `alpha`.

Comment: The problem with `key` is that it does not force the label (see [tame the beast § 6.1, p. 13](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf) "[`key` is] [u]sed for defining the label, in case it cannot be computed by BibTeX. It does not force the label, but defines the label when BibTeX needs one but can’t compute it."). Would you terribly mind using `biblatex`? `biblatex` provides `shorthand` ([§ 2.2.2, p. 22: "This field is intended for citation aliasing. If defined, it overrides the default label."](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)).

Comment: I'd like to emphasize that, as noted by moewe, **`biblatex` provides the `shorthand` key** serving this purpose and easily fixing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to load the `natbib` citation management package and use that package's `\defcitealias` macro to define, you guessed it, a "citation alias" of the form "CGAL". Then, use `\citetalias{CGAL}` instead of `\cite{CGAL}` to generate a citation call-out that uses the alias.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{CGAL,
  key   = "CGAL",
  title = {{CGAL, Computational Geometry Algorithms Library}},
  note  = "\url{http://www.cgal.org}",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\defcitealias{CGAL}{CGAL}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{url,hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=red} % just for this example

\begin{document}
\noindent
\cite{CGAL} or \citetalias{CGAL} or [\citetalias{CGAL}]

\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Now it is experiment time :-) [How can I explain the meaning of LaTeX to my grandma?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/749344)