# How to keep a "rare" ligature from interfering with a "common" ligature?

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, fontspec, ligatures

In ligature-rich Opentype fonts which feature both "common" and "rare" ligatures, it can happen that a "rare" ligature is applied first to one character pair, pre-empting the use of a "common" or "rare" ligature that ought to be applied to the preceding or trailing character pair. (Regarding ligature terminology in Opentype fonts: Most, but not all, Opentype font families I'm familiar with classify the f-ligatures -- `ff`, `fi`, `fl`, `ffi`, `ffl`, and possibly also `ft`, `fft`, and a few more -- as "common" and all others as either "rare"/"discretionary" or "historic". )

Two examples of this behavior, which can arise with both XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX:

- With the font `Garamond Premier Pro`, the "rare" `is` ligature is applied first to words such as `fish` and `fist`, pre-empting the use of the "common" `fi` ligature.
- With the font `Junicode`, the "rare" `iv` and `ix` ligatures are applied first to words such as `five`, `fix`, and `affixed`, pre-empting the use of the "common" `fi` and `ffi` ligatures.

[image]

Without this pre-emption, the output would look like this (achieved the "brute force" way, i.e., by inserting `\kern0pt` between `i` and `s`, `i` and `v`, and `i` and `x`, respectively):

[image]

(Observe, by the way, that the brute-force suppression of the rare `is` ligature in the word "fist" not only enables the common `fi` ligature but also the rare `st` ligature.)

**Question**: Which methods may be available -- ideally on a document-wide basis -- that prevent the application of certain rare ligatures if they pre-empt other, either common or rare, ligatures?

Aside: This posting is not a duplicate of the earlier posting [How to suppress a "Rare" ligature that pre-empts a "Common" ligature for the same character pair?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89963/5001) In the earlier question, the issue was that "rare" and "common" forms of a given ligature could be present for one and the same character pair (or triple). Examples of this issue are common and rare forms of ligatures for "ft" and "fft".

---

Here's the code that gives rise to the second screenshot shown above; remove the `\kern0pt` directives to generate the first screenshot:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}

\setmainfont[Ligatures  = Rare,
             ItalicFont = {Garamond Premier Pro Italic}]           
            {Garamond Premier Pro}

% 'is'-ligature available only in italic shape in GPP
\emph{fi\kern0ptsh fi\kern0ptst} --- Garamond Premier Pro

\setmainfont[Ligatures = Rare]{Junicode}

fi\kern0ptve fi\kern0ptx affi\kern0ptx --- Junicode

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is other software affected by the same issue?

Comment: @egreg - I'm pretty sure the issue isn't related to `luaotfload`, as it can arise under XeLaTeX as well as under LuaLaTeX. Note also that it doesn't affect all font families which feature both common and rare ligatures. For instance, the `is` ligature does *not* pre-empt the `fi` and `st` ligatures if `EB Garamond` is used instead of `Garamond Premier Pro`. I don't have access to desktop publishing packages such as InDesign; hence, I can't tell if this issue arises with other software as well.

Comment: Yes, I was exactly pointing to appications such as InDesign. An attempt should be made with it or similar application.

Comment: @egreg - I'd also be most curious to learn from anybody who happens to have InDesign (or a similarly capable application) if the issue described above occurs with these fonts if both common and rare ligatures are enabled.

Comment: the `0pt` kern suppresses defined kerning, which appears to be needed.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Indeed, the essence of the zero-width kern is that it's not "discarded" (using TeX jargon) and hence serves reliably to inhibit any ligatures that might otherwise be inserted. In contrast, as I'm sure you're aware of, the `{}`-method of preventing ligatures does not work at all under Lua(La)TeX -- and it doesn't even work 100% of the time under pdf(La)TeX. Inserting an italics correction wouldn't be right for the case at hand, since there should be no gap between, say, `fi` and `st` in the word `fist`.

Comment: @Mico -- what i *really* meant is that i believe there is a small kern defined for "is" that is suppressed when the explicit `0pt` is inserted.  try setting "is" with and without that kern; i think you'll see that without the explicit kern, the two letters are a wee bit closer together.  ("defined" kerns are the reason why it's so complicated to define a good letterspacing macro.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Thanks for providing this clarification. :-) With Adobe's Garamond Premier Pro font's italic font shape in use, and without rare ligatures enabled, `\em is\kern-5.45pt\color{red}i\kern0pts` produces a perfect overlay, i.e, the black and red `i`'s and the black and red `s`'s, respectively, are perfectly on top of each other. I'm thus not so sure that the zero-width kern eliminates any (horizontal) whitespace between the letters.

Comment: @Mico -- thanks for checking.  what about "iv", as in "five"?  (and i wouldn't expect to *eliminate* any space, rather to add, albeit a very small amount.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Same result, i.e., no difference, with Junicode upright font shape and `ix` character pair, with and without `\kern0pt` between `i` and `x`, using both LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In my view, the following ligature suppression rules are needed.

- In order to enable the `fi` ligature, suppress the `is`, `iv`, and `ix` ligatures **if** `is`/`iv`/`ix` is preceded by `f`;
- In order to enable the `sp` and `st` ligatures, suppress the `is` ligature **if** `is` is followed by either `p` or `t`.

In the jargon of Opentype fonts, `fi` is called a common ligature, and `is`, `iv`, and `ix`, as well as `sp` and `st`, are called rare or discretionary ligatures.

The following solution, which works under LuaLaTeX (but not under XeLaTeX), employs the [selnolig](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/luatex/latex/selnolig) package. (Full disclosure: I'm the main author of the `selnolig` package.) The ligature suppression rules given above are implemented via several `\nolig` instructions:

```
\nolig{fis}{fi|s} % break up 'is' lig. if preceded by 'f'
\nolig{fiv}{fi|v} % break up 'iv' lig. if preceded by 'f'
\nolig{fix}{fi|x} % break up 'ix' lig. if preceded by 'f'
\nolig{isp}{i|sp} % break up 'is' lig. if followed by 'p'
\nolig{ist}{i|st} % break up 'is' lig. if followed by 't'
```

More concisely, one would write:

```
\nolig{fi[svx]}{fi|.}
\nolig{is[pt]}{i|s.}
```

The `.` character after the `|` is shorthand for "any glyph". I'm not sure if the increase in terseness and density is worth the cost of reduced (human) legibility.

If one wanted to suppress the `is`, `iv`, and `ix` ligatures *globally*, while still allowing other "rare" ligatures to be used, a single `\nolig` instruction would do the job:

```
\nolig{i[svx]}{i|.}
```

---

In the following code, the upright shape of `Junicode` is used for the `iv` and `ix` cases, and the italic shape is used of `Garamond Premier Pro` is used for the `sp` and `st` ligatures. The first data row shows the outcome with `selnolig` being "on"; for comparison, the second data row shows the outcome with `selnolig` being turned "off".

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,booktabs}
\setmainfont[Ligatures  = Rare,
             ItalicFeatures = {Scale = MatchLowercase},
             ItalicFont = {Garamond Premier Pro Italic}]
            {Junicode}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Palatino Sans Com}

\usepackage{selnolig}
\nolig{fis}{fi|s} % break up 'is' lig. if preceded by 'f'
\nolig{fiv}{fi|v} % break up 'iv' lig. if preceded by 'f'
\nolig{fix}{fi|x} % break up 'ix' lig. if preceded by 'f'
\nolig{isp}{i|sp} % break up 'is' lig. if followed by 'p'
\nolig{ist}{i|st} % break up 'is' lig. if followed by 't'

%% Or, more concisely:
% \nolig{fi[svx]}{fi|.}
% \nolig{is[pt]}{i|s.}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
\textsf{selnolig} & Junicode: iv, ix  & \em Gar.\ Prem.\ Pro Italic: is\\
\midrule
On & five fix affix & \em fish fissure fist gist lisp\\[0.5ex]
\selnoligoff % turn off selnolig's operations
Off & five fix affix & \em fish fissure fist gist lisp\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interested in answering that one? [Cite software/libraries using bibtex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132669) :-) Or do you know a good duplicate?